# Wordpress CRUD page is not passing ID to the update page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a calculator result page that is pulled from a database that looks ok. When I click the update button the url does not pass the ID correctly.

Instead of the URL passing .... /soap_recipe_update.php?id=92
(or whatever id)
It always shows ...../soap_recipe_update.php?id=9669 (the same incorrect ID)

This was all working fine for several months and just started acting badly with nothing altered.

In the header I have

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Here is the button

```
 <a href="soap_recipe_update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" >
```

Here is the wpdb update code in my process file

```
function soap_calculator_update($id){
         global $wpdb;
         $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'TABLE_NAME_HERE';
       if(isset($_POST['update_soap_recipe'])){
         $recipe_name=$_POST['recipe_name'];
         $recipe_notes=$_POST['recipe_notes'];
         $wpdb->update( $table_name,
                             array('recipe_name'=>$recipe_name,
                                   'recipe_notes'=>$recipe_notes ),
                             array('id'=>$id)    
                          );
                     } 
                   }
```

I have looked for more ways to pass the ID but every resource I have brings me back to this code, which was working for so long.